# Replace NA with previous character for certain column add some letter in R

Tags: r, zoo

I want to convert `NA` to a certain character, based on the given variable value for that specific names. Sample query

```
df1 = data.frame(session=c("breakfast","breakfast", "breakfast", "NA","lunch","lunch","lunch","NA","dinner","dinner","dinner","NA"))
```

Where NAs I need a result like this

```
df2 = data.frame(session=c("breakfast","breakfast", "breakfast", "breakfast Total","lunch","lunch","lunch","lunch Total","dinner","dinner","dinner","dinner Total"))
```

Comment: There is a package called `zoo` in R that has a `na.locf` function

Comment: I made some mistake, can you tell answer

Comment: `df1 %>% mutate(session = ifelse(is.na(session), paste(lead(session), "Total", sep = " "), as.character(session)))`

Comment: Forget what I said previously. I was thinking about last one forward.